# What is the complain mechanism for EL&U?

Tags: discussion

I asked a very sincere [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/281278) and it was put on hold for being *too broad*. 
The question was :

**"What is the euphemism for `motherfucker`"**

The idea behind the question was to learn to express very strong emotions without being cheap. This is a valid pursuit and the question attracted quite a few good answers before being closed by some.

Comment: You can complain here, but I don't see the point of it at all. No one with the ability to un-close your question is likely to be convinced to by what you're saying.

Comment: @sumelic, so the moderators have a reputation of being obstinate too, I see. I just heard they are arrogant and unwelcoming towards new users.

Comment: You're not being very polite yourself. It's not appropriate to call other site members "mother-huggers" even if you disagree with their actions. That was what I meant. The moderators are not necessarily obstinate, but you are not approaching them in a productive way.

Comment: I was making a point; the question was useful after all.

Comment: Your use of the term *mother-huggers* was misinterpreted by more people than just me; I'd advise you to edit the post and remove it to prevent it from becoming a distraction from your actual goals.

Comment: I have edited the question, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Dear Sir or Madame, Welcome to the site. I see you feel your superior insights (for example, passing judgements on the moderators here) are not appreciated as the unimpeachable observations that you know they are. The best approach to this quandry is to leave the site in a huff and never look back. Please remember that you know much more English than we do, know what is offensive and what is not to native speakers, and we have nothing of value to offer one as advanced as you are.

Comment: We are losing focus here. I love the site and will stay, even if it is this unwelcoming. Let me know what was my question missing and I will pest no more. Also, don't pride yourself on being a native speaker. *Being native speaker doth butter no parsnips*

Comment: There were too many possible answers, I came up with *despicable despot*, which is not vulgar, crude, or a taboo word. But someone else could have suggested *son of a bitch*, or just plain *nasty person*. I also find it incredibly hard to believe that someone whose English is really good like yours, couldn't come up with anyhing themselves. If you know the term *motherfucker* you know also much milder ones.

Comment: The complain mechanism was used properly and you have received good answers. Also, I don't pride myself on being a native speaker any more than the fish doth pride himself on being an able swimmer. I merely pointed out that you are as far superior to us as our insect overlords. Now please butter no parsnips and pest no more.

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary I couldn't see the question as it is removed but I must say that passing judgement on moderators and fellow users(more experienced with the site usage) when you have been here merely for 9 days and posted your first question, makes you sound conceited to be honest. Everyone gets their questions closed as off-topic every now and then, more likely when they are just a newbie but no need to lose your sleep over it. Perhaps this link may be helpful to you: http://english.stackexchange.com/help/behavior. Nobody is morally obliged to address your issue, so **be nice** while talking

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 5):

As sumelic has commented, you can complain here.

Despite feeling the answers were "good", it looks as though you didn't upvote any of them* because the one which has upvotes has a comment from you expressing dissatisfaction.

Your question was not put on hold as too broad, although that **was** mentioned in a comment:

> This is too broad. Your question asks for a euphemism. But your comment wants something harsher. Can you be more explicit? We're not mind readers. What exactly do you want? What is the situation?

It received two close-votes as "Primarily opinion based", before a moderator closed it for lack of research. However, "unclear what you are asking" would have been equally valid, as that comment demonstrates.

The question was then flagged as offensive and deleted.

ELU *does* allow terms which are offensive, because this is a site about language. However, if you want to ask about offensive language in a question such as yours, you need to be very careful to explain the circumstances and the requirement **exactly,** or you risk just being seen as a troll who is using offensive language on the site simply because it's allowed. If you have a real question, **demonstrate** that it's a real question.

(I would also counsel against calling people names in Meta, as it really doesn't help your case. *Mother-hugger* is a fairly obvious euphemism.)

---

*Moderators can't see votes; we have to guess from the same evidence as everyone else.

Comment: Thanks for your response, a few quick points :
i) I do not yet have to privilege to up-vote. Also, note the edit history of the answer with up-votes. I made the comment, the answer was edited and only after that it got up-votes. In fact, earlier it was *down-voted*

Comment: ii). I do not think my question was *offensive*.Talking about a derogatory term does not make it offensive. *Lacks research* ?
I think [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229346/what-is-the-origin-of-rat) question lacks research. *Too broad* ? I was asking for *one* word is all.

Comment: iii) I did not wish to call anyone *mother-huggers*, I just wished to make a point; that the question is useful, it taught me that word for example.

Comment: (1) Noted. (2) No, talking about an offensive term in objective terms is fine. But just because there are questions without research doesn't make it OK for all, **especially** for contentious questions such as this. *Too broad* means there are too many possible one-word answers. (3) Thank you for editing your Meta post.

Comment: A question having many possible answers is the beauty of the English language. It doesn't necessary imply the question was ill-posed ? How do I improve the question ?

Comment: A good question has just one right answer. There may be many attempts at that right answer, but only one will satisfy all the criteria you specify. Your criteria need to narrow down the scope of answers, not broaden it.